# CartoCSS files for Metro Extracts

Tags: tilemill, cartocss

I downloaded the Milan shapefiles from [Metro Extracts](https://mapzen.com/data/metro-extracts/) and I imported these into TileMill.

Do any CartoCSS files exist to define all layers in the shapefile, or do they need to be created from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

See the [Create a custom map tutorial](http://www.mapbox.com/blog/create-a-custom-map-of-your-city-in-30-minutes-with-tilemill-and-openstreetmap/) that uses [osm-bright](https://github.com/mapbox/osm-bright) for that.